# I keep getting a syntax error when trying to insert a date into a comment string and updating the file

Tags: c#, xamarin

```
var dat = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
comment = dat.ToString();
comment = comment += "  ";
comment = comment += txtComment.Text + NewLine;

ssl = $"update dbo.steak set comment={comment} where fileid={r2}";
using (command = new SqlCommand(ssl, sqlConnection));
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The text in txtComment.Text is "bad steak" and the error is incorrect syntax near 'bad'
The complete comment reads "06/03/2022  bad steak"
I have tried several different ways to write the comment but keep getting the error, always after the date in the string.  Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps show were `comment` is declared;   Not sure why you have the `dat.ToString()` which seems redundant given the prior is a string

Comment: I have a reader string to get the comment  string comment = reader["comment"].ToString();

Comment: `comment = comment += "  ";` is equal to `comment = comment = comment +  "  "`. Do you see any error???

Comment: If the SQL code is producing the error, the first debugging step is to examine the SQL code.  What is the exact runtime value of `ssl` which produces the error?  Is it what you expect it to be?  (Also, correcting the SQL injection problem will likely render this error moot...)

Comment: also, you need to clarify what the error actually is.  A syntax error appears at compile time, an exception will occur at run time.  It is always helpful to include the **exact** error message in your post

Comment: Do you see where this is vulnerable to a SQL injection?  Probably want to update prior to moving this to production.
`ssl = $"update dbo.steak set comment={comment} where fileid={r2}";`

Comment: yes, the ssl is "update steak set comment = '06/03/2022 bad steak' where fileid = 1"

Comment: the exact error message is "Incorrect syntax near 'good'."

Comment: @dkaveritt: That exact SQL code doesn't produce that exact error.  It sounds like you may be making some assumptions in your debugging...

Comment: I used this as my comment and killed your database:  "'bad steak';drop table dbo.steak--"

Comment: is this a RUNTIME exception or a compile-time error?  If it's an exception, which **specific line** throws it and what is the exact Exception type and error?  We are having to make guesses about what is wrong because you are not supplying enough information.

Comment: update dbo.steak set comment=bad food where fileid=1

Comment: @dkaveritt: That code clearly has a syntax error because string values need to be wrapped in single-quotes in SQL.  Correct the SQL injection problem (use parameterized queries) and you won't have this error.

Comment: you would avoid all of this if you used SQLite.NET's ORM instead of raw SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Parameterize the SQL
- Fix the using (I use old style syntax for clarity
- I used "fake" variables for clarity
- This is not fully complete nor is this production ready but should demonstrate the basic principles and resolve your issue.

  ```
    var dat = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    int r2 = 563; //fake an id
    string sqlComnnection = "sometthing connection";
    string txtComment = "Bad Steak'';drop table dbo.steak--";
    var nowDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    string comment = $"{nowDate} {txtComment}{Environment.NewLine}";
    var sqlText = @"
        UPDATE dbo.steak 
        SET comment = @comment 
        WHERE fileid = @r2;
        ";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(sqlComnnection))
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@comment", comment) {SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar});
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@r2", r2) {SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int});
            command.CommandText = sqlText;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
  ```

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I tried it and it works great.  I changed all my updates to use Parameters and it works like a charm.  Appreciate the help.